# Update ng2 chart with multiple datasets

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

I have 3 sets of data where i have to show each one of the data-set one after other in the chart like for first 5 seconds it should display dataset 1 and for next 5 seconds next datset

I tried using updatechart function,but its not working

```js
export class AcidLineChartComponent implements OnInit {
  public lineChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { data: [33, 4, 21, 35, 67, 8, 34] },
    { data: [34,4,61,43,65,8,12,0,45] },
    { data: [23,4,12,34,65,78,90,56] }

  ];

  public lineChartLabels: Array<any> = [1522.37, 1522.40, 1522.43, 1522.46, 1522.49, 1522.52, 1522.55, 1522.58];

  public randomize(): void {
    const lineChartData: ChartDataSets[] = new Array(this.lineChartData.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < this.lineChartData.length; i++) {
      lineChartData[i] = { data: new Array(this.lineChartData[i].data.length), label: this.lineChartData[i].label };
      for (let j = 0; j < this.lineChartData[i].data.length; j++) {
        lineChartData[i].data[j] = Math.floor((Math.random() * (i < 2 ? 100 : 1000)) + 1);
      }
    }
    this.lineChartData = lineChartData;
  }



  updateChart(){
    let _dataSets:Array<any> = new Array(this.lineChartData.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < this.lineChartData.length; i++) {
       _dataSets[i] = {data: new Array(this.lineChartData[i].data.length), label: this.lineChartData[i].label};
       for (let j = 0; j < this.lineChartData[i].data.length; j++) {
         _dataSets[i].data[j] = this.lineChartData[i].data[j];
       }
    }
    this.lineChartData = _dataSets;
    // this.lineChartData = this.lineChartData.slice()
  }


}
```

I want to show chart where it has to display linechartdata one after the other. Currently I am getting three charts at a time.
can some suggest  the answer..Thanks in advance.